# enabled button if listview item checked

Tags: vb.net, listview

How can I enable a button if an item is checked in a listview? I've tried this and fiddled with it but no luck. Can anyone help?

```
Private Sub lvCustomers_SelectedIndexChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles lvCustomers.SelectedIndexChanged
    For Each x As ListViewItem In lvCustomers.Items
        If x.Checked Then
            btnConfirmOrder.Enabled = True
        ElseIf x.Checked = False Then
            btnConfirmOrder.Enabled = False
        End If
    Next
End Sub
```

Comment: Your "luck" ran out because you are looping theru them all so the button will only reflect the result of the last item.  Please read [ask] and take the [tour]

Comment: How are you binding to the XAML? Show more code please.

Comment: I would put this in the ItemChecked event so that it triggers the code when you click a checkbox. I would also just base it off of the count of the checkeditems collection being greater than 0. (Assuming this is winforms and you're wanting the result to happen when you check a checkbox)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's an example using the event and collection I was describing in my comment

```
Private Sub ListView1_ItemChecked(sender As Object, e As ItemCheckedEventArgs) Handles lvCustomers.ItemChecked
    'checkeditems collection keeps track of only items that are checked
    'if a single item is checked lvCustomer.CheckedItems.Count > 0
    'becomes true and therefore the button is enabled. This event
    'will respond with any check or uncheck of a checkbox in the LV
    btnConfirmOrder.Enabled = lvCustomers.CheckedItems.Count > 0
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Private Sub lvCustomers_SelectedIndexChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles lvCustomers.SelectedIndexChanged
    btnConfirmOrder.Enabled = lvCustomers.Items.Any(Function(x) x.Checked)
End Sub
```